# Internal Server Error with Magento as well as site trying to rewrite to something strange

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I've copied & installed the database for a Magento site for a client.  I don't have much experience in Magento but I get a strange error condition

When you type in www.example.com it automatically re-writes the URL to www.example.com/sites/example.com/index.php

It also produces a 500 error as well.

Anyone got any clue on how to fix this?  Please remember I am a Magento newbie.

**EDIT**
The problem was down to the server setup :(  There was an issue with the "webroot"

Comment: You have an htaccess file you can post?

Comment: I had a double check of the htaccess file and found "Redirect 301 /home http://www.example.com".  commented that out and BINGO the /sites/example.com issue went away.  Now I get a, straight, 500 error.  Is this now a Magento install problem?

Comment: just checked it again * it is back to before.  Ran the site with the .htaccess file removed & it still produces the same result as above... I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

go to `core_config_data table. There are a couple of fields you need to edit so the urls match your http://localhost/mysite/` but make sure you have the trailing slash on the site path.
base urls

Edit these base urls

These tell the database where to point your links between pages and content.

```
moving files and database

I assume these two steps are obvious:

    copy all of your local files to production server
    dump your magento local db and import it into your production server db

editing in production server

now on your production server you need to follow these two steps:



      edit app/etc/local.xml file and change database info

        in production db,in its core_config_data table, you should find every records containing the url of your local installation, then you need to update those values;which can be found with this query:


         SELECT *
         FROM `core_config_data`
         WHERE `value` LIKE 'http://%';

    edit (thanks to comments):
   Do not forget to delete var folder contents
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've done all of that & checked the core_config_data.  They are all correct :(

It's the issue of the 301 from ww.example.com to www.example.com/sites/example.com/index.php is the issue